# Why is a user randomly created in AWS RDS even though the permissions from any host (%) exist?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I have a MySQL database in RDS. There are separate users which are allowed to connect from anywhere. To be more precise, using MySQL Workbench there are different users listed in "Users and Priviliges" with "From Host" entry of "%".

The developers connect via ssh port forwarding over AWS SSM. All except one developer can connect to the database without problems. This developer has an "%" entry for "From Host" just like everybody else. Nevertheless, sometimes - seemingly random - there is a new user created with specific ip in "From Host". At this point there are multiple users with the same name, one with "%" and the other one with a specific ip. As a result this user is not able to perform any action on the database.

After deletion of this user entry, the user can access the database without any problems but at some point the user entry with a specific ip gets recreated and the described problem comes back.

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this issue or what is causing the issue in the first place?

Comment: Entries in the `user` table don't just randomly appear out of nowhere; someone or something must run the `create user` command or directly insert those rows.

Comment: @mustaccio do you know by chance if such a `create user` command is possibly run under the hood while establishing a connection via a (.NET Core) SQL client?